# Swift 3 Compile error. Cannot convert type () to type int

Tags: compiler-errors, swift3

I'm attempting to learn Swift 3 and I've been doing well with the conversion from 2.3 to 3. However, I'm getting a compile error when trying to run

```
var time = 0

func result() {
    time +=

    print(time)
}
```

I understand that this is answered other places but none in regard to the exact error I'm getting:

```
Cannot convert value of type '()'to expected argument type 'Int'
```

I've tried all my tricks like putting time as

```
print("\(time)")
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out what's going on, and I don't understand what the error is trying to say.

Comment: What's `time +=`? That's not a valid line of code.

Comment: So I left out the 1 in 
    time += 1
so that it increments by 1 each step through. 'Var' += replaces 'i++' in Swift 3, which is throwing me off as I'm used to the latter. It's caused me a few issues. I apologize if you already knew this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code you are telling the complier that there is a value after 
time += which leads to through complie time error, as the next step is a void type not the Int type that why it through error .

```
var time = 0

func result() {
    time += 1
    print(time)

}
```

You can try the above code.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. It was an issue with me, not reading properly, I was under the belief that the += would automatically increment by 1 so I left off the actual amount to increase by.